# can't get rid of security error in flash applet - crossdomain.xml seems to be ignored

Tags: flash, audio-streaming, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to setup a streamingserver.
I have one server, called foo.net wich is hosting the ssl-secured website with the flash based player applet (musesplayer). The URL for this would be https://foo.net/music/i/player

I have a second server, called bar.net wich is running icecast2 and is serving the stream on port 80, 443 (ssl secured) and 8000.
An example URL fo a stream would be http://bar.net:80/mystream.ogg (replace http with https for the ssl-secured variant)

For some reasons I can't get it to work on port 80 and 443. Only with port 8000 it seems to be working.

Every time I'm trying to access the stream via port 80 and 443, I'm getting a security error. The docs for my playerapplet suggest to install a utf-8 encoded crossdomain.xml into the root of the streamingserver. So I googled around an came up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="*"/>    
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I know that this is overly permissive but I want to get it working before I start to tighten access. 
Anyway, it doesn't work. Im still getting security error.

Can anyone help me here with this?

with kind regards,
errorsmith

Comment: Could you show us the security error ? And, what do you get when opening : http://bar.net:80/crossdomain.xml ?

Comment: The applet shows just the notice "security error". Nothing more.
Can I activate some kind of logging in chromium or firefox to get more info here?

When open the address bar.net:80/crossdomain.xml I get the content of my crossdomain.xml as shown above. According to firefox it is utf-8 encoded as it should be.

with kind regards,
errorsmith

Comment: I meant open the url in your browser.

Comment: I know. I'm just getting my crossdomain.xml as explained above
The same happens with bar.net:443/crossdomain.xml

Comment: Is there a possibility to give us a test url to better see things ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have not the permission to give away the login data needed to access the site with the player applet and the stream and I have not the permission to make the music wich is streamed publicly available. This is a private project, intended to be accessible to a very limited number of people. Sorry for that. I know it doesn't make it easier to help me.

Comment: OK, no problem, I understand. So we will try to do some tests. Could you try your player in chrome (for example) with the developer tools activated and tell me what you see in the Network tab, which files is trying to get ?

Comment: No Problem. I configured the applet to try the ssl-secured version on port 443 first and fall back to the unsecured version on port 8000 if this doesn't work.

So, after loading the html-page it loads:
- style.css
- muses.swf (this is the applet)
- ffmp3-simple-blue.xml (the skin for the applet)
- Some graphics for the Skin

Whe I press the "play" button, it asks for the login-data wich are needed to access the stream, then loads https://bar.net:443/crossdomain.xml. After that it tries to get https://bar.net:443/mystream.ogg, this fails and the plugin reports "security error".

Comment: How did you get the security error ? Are you using a flash player debug version or you have some log in your swf ? What about trying the ogg url directly in the browser ? If you have the details of the security error, put it to know exactly the origin of the problem.

Comment: The applet has a textarea where it shows things like artist/title or the name of the stream. Instead of this streamname it shows the text "security error".

I have no debug-version of flashplayer available and no idea how to get more logging (but would be happy if there was a way to get some).

I can reach the ogg url with any browser and depending on wich one the browser plays it (chrome, firefox) or tries to open it with an external application (konqueror). I can also play it with VLC and mplayer.

Comment: I think that you have to get the details of that error. Could you do that by editing your swf ? also, could you put the ogg file in the same server as the swf and try to play it ? Could you tell me what's the http code for the crossdomain.xml and the ogg file in the browser network logging tab ? Could you also try your page with another browser ?

Comment: How do I need to edit the swf file? It's a precompiled file I downloaded from the website https://www.muses.org.
The ogg file is not a file but a stream from the streamingserver (icecast2) so I can't move it to the webserver.
The crossdomain.xml gets http code 200, the mystream.ogg gets no http code, it gets net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I tried the page with firefox, chromium and konqueror from my computer and my laptop. I also tried with chrome, firefox and the native "browser" from my smartphone. I have no Internet Explorer available to test it.